# Spring Cloud Data Flow Server for OpenShift

Tags: spring, openshift, spring-cloud-dataflow

Need to setup Spring Cloud Data Flow Server on Openshift. Is there any reference or official docker image that can be used?

Answer (score 1):

The Spring-team do not officially build, maintain, or release the SCDF implementation for Openshift; however, we have a community implementation developed by [ABSA](https://www.absa.co.za/) in South Africa.

More details about the implementation [here](https://github.com/donovanmuller/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-openshift).

Answer (score 0):

Just checking if SCDF is now officially supported on OpenShift since its been over one year since your last comment above.. we are planning to use SCDF in our project and OpenShift is one of the deployment options in front of us. But if SCDF is still not officially supported then we have to reevaluate our options. Can you please confirm.

Comment: You ever get any additional info on this? Looking into something similar and about to give a deployment on Openshift a go.

Comment: I got it working in OSE with some pretty minor tweaks from the publicly available repos... I can post something here shortly on what I did if wanted...

Comment: Hi @Funsaized can you share what you have gotten working please.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello @Funsaized, it would be helpful if you kindly share your workaround here.